# Select all nodes with a certain name by using PHP SimpleXML - source code attached

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

In the following XML file I'm trying to print all `TestItem` nodes, but get only the 4 `outer` nodes.

Does anybody please know, how to print every node having that name, regardless of their position?

**data.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tests>
    <TestItem Name="UpdateBootProfile" Result="PASS" />
    <TestItem Name="NRB Boot" Result="PASS">
      <TestItem Name="Boot Test" Result="PASS">
        <TestItem Name="PreparePowerSupply" Result="PASS" />
        <TestItem Name="ApplyBatteryVoltage" Result="PASS" />
        <TestItem Name="Shelf Mode test" Result="PASS">
        </TestItem>
        <TestItem Name="ApplyUSBVoltage" Result="PASS" />
        <TestItem Name="DetectBoard" Result="PASS" />
        <TestItem Name="Device Current Profile" Result="PASS" />
        <TestItem Name="Device Connection" Result="PASS">
        </TestItem>
      </TestItem>
    </TestItem>
    <TestItem Name="Check device Type" Result="PASS" />
    <TestItem Name="Assign BSN and Erase EFS" Result="PASS">
    </TestItem>
</Tests>
```

**parse.php:**

```
<?php
        $tmp = 'data.xml';
        $str = file_get_contents($tmp);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
        $items = $xml->xpath('TestItem');

        while(list( , $test) = each($items)) {
                printf("%s %s\n", $test['Name'], $test['Result']);
        }
?>
```

**php -f parse.php** output (why does it list only 4 TestItems?):

```
UpdateBootProfile PASS
NRB Boot PASS
Check device Type PASS
Assign BSN and Erase EFS PASS
```

Using PHP 5.3.5 on CentOS 6.3 command line.

**UPDATE:**

The suggested `//TestItem` works for my simple test case above, thank you.

But it still fails for my real data (which I can't paste here):

```
# grep -w TestItem my_real_file_May_2013_09_35_38.xml |wc -l
143

# php -f parse.php |wc -l
86
```

Does anybody please have an idea, which would `//TestItem` miss some nodes?

**UPDATE 2:**

Actually it works! The grep commando above counted more lines because of some `</TestItem>` closing tags :-)

Comment: Because you have no difference between parent and child elements like `<TestItem>'. You have parent element `<TestItem>` and same with `<TestItem>` elements. This should not be there.

Comment: Paste the xml to pastebin and share the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
$testitems = simplexml_load_file("testitem.xml");
if(count($testitems)):
    $result = $testitems->xpath("//TestItem");

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($result);die;
    foreach ($result as $item):
        echo "Name ".$item['Name'] ." and result ". $item['Result'];
        echo "<hr>";
    endforeach;
endif;
```

By doing above you will get all elements haveing `<TestItem>` elements.

Comment: Thank you, `//TestItem` works for my simple example, but it doesn't work for my real file, which I may not paste here. Do you have an idea why/when `//TestItem` would omit some nodes? I have updated my question

Comment: @AlexanderFarber take a look on my answer i've edited to fit your propous.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: `//TestItem` should work and give all matching elements. Can you provide just one sample of your complicated file? So that I can get better idea.

Comment: Actually you're correct! Thank you. I was confused by the `</TestItem>` tags (the `grep` counted them too)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following xpath to select nodes regardless from their position in tree:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//TestItem');
```

Or

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//TestItem/TestItem');
```

If you only need the leaf nodes.

Output (from second one):

```
UpdateBootProfile PASS
NRB Boot PASS
Boot Test PASS
PreparePowerSupply PASS
ApplyBatteryVoltage PASS
Shelf Mode test PASS
ApplyUSBVoltage PASS
DetectBoard PASS
Device Current Profile PASS
Device Connection PASS
Check device Type PASS
Assign BSN and Erase EFS PASS
```

Note the `//`. Learn more about in the [W3schools XPath tutorial.](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: I _guess_ you're downvoted [because of the w3schools link](http://w3fools.com), so I suggest you to replace it with [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath#Axis_specifiers)...

Comment: @Passerby Thank you. But how can somebody (Guerra) tell me what I've to link and what not? I've linked a perfect tutorial and presented the right expression

Comment: @hek2mgl "w3schools sucks" is one of the common war cry in SO...kind of like using `mysql_*` in PHP :) avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you for that hint ;).. Will take this in account in upcoming posts. (this one I won't update, because I thought the down-vote was rude and offensive).. But, thanks again ;)

Comment: @Guerra Can you point me to some wrong or insufficient information in that tutorial?

Comment: I don't care about which sites you like or dislike. I just want to know what exactly is the problem with this answer. Did it not working for you? Or did you find some misleading content in my link?

Answer (score -1):

```
function printxml($xml,$deep = 4){
if($xml instanceOf SimpleXMLElement)
    $xml = (array)$xml;
    foreach($xml->TestItem as $t){
        if(is_array($t) && $deep > 0)
            printxml($t, $deep-1);
        else
            echo $t['Name'].' '.$t['Result'];
    }
}
```

Try it, just have to do counter to get the deep of xml, in your case 4 levels.

Comment: Above code only prints 4 records as that was the original question.

Comment: Thank you, but I better hope to find a good XPath expression - because my real file is more complicated...

Comment: LOL! :D Note the question is tagged XPath. This is actually DOM traversal (at it's worst)

Comment: @hek2mgl que question isn't about XPath, if you read the title he want select some node with PHP, this code can do it. XPath come on other answers.

Comment: check the tags (they are for that)